# c# execute CMD command "SQLCMD -L" programmatically and get returned results?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

This is my code, there is no output.
I want the list of instance like the image illustrate

```
namespace InstanceList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cmd = "SQLCMD -L" ; 
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd; 
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
            proc.Start();
            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `SQLCMD -L` to `/C SQLCMD -L`, why not just set `FileName= "sqlcmd"` and `Arguments  = "-L"`